# How to override System.Windows.Forms label background color in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, overriding

I'm trying to write a class to override ALL my label backgrounds in my entire project without changing their definition in designer.cs files.
I mean I could simply change `this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();` to something like `this.label1 = new myLabel();` but I don't want to do this.
This is my label.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace T1
{

    class Label:System.Windows.Forms.Label
    {
        public override Color BackColor
        {
            get
            {
                return Color.DarkRed;
            }
            set
            {
                base.BackColor = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to call my namespace System.Windows.Forms in hope to override it's current label color property, but I couldn't get anywhere so far.
Any help would be appreciated.
All the Best.

Comment: Overriding the labels would probably be the right approach, second to this you could make your own custom form class to inherit from that does a separate `Initialize` step but then that creates an overhead too

Comment: @Sayse mmmm, sounds like a good choice. Would you please provide a code sample which I can learn from? It would be so much appreciated.

Comment: First of all - make this class public and change the name to MyLabel or something

Comment: @MajkeloDev I made it public. But the point is if I change the class name from `label` to something else, then I would have to change `this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label(); ` to `this.label1 = new myLabel(); ` for instance which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Sam - I've added an answer to demonstrate the form approach, if this isn't of any use, please let me know and I will delete the answer.

Comment: Oh now I get Your point. I don't think it's achievable in that manner. I believe that controls were designed to be inherited not fully overrided

Comment: @MajkeloDev Thanks for your response! Do you have any document, link or anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

First, let me start by saying that I think it really sounds like you would be better off by replacing references with your overridden label as you have mentioned (maybe not by editing the designer.cs but by replacing the controls)

But in further to my comment, you can create your own form to override all your forms that require its controls adjusted like this and then inherit from that form

```
class MyMiddleFormClass : Form
{
     public MyMiddleFormClass()
     {
          this.OnLoad += OnLoadHandler;
     }

     private void OnLoadHandler(object o, EventArgs e)
     {
          foreach(var lbl in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
              lbl.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
     }
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this code and may require extra work if you need to use the OnLoad event yourself.

Again, you would benefit a lot more by spending the time now refactoring your controls instead of doing this.